# ElasticSearch inconsistent relevance

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to do search for movies by the actors that played in them.  When I search for e.g. "leonardo dicaprio" there are 10 or so movies that I get back but they all have a different score.  Since they all have the same actor I would expect them to have the same score.  Is anyone able to shed some light on why this is happening and hopefully how to stop it?

Elasticsearch version 1.7.2

Mapping:

```
    {
  "programs": {
    "mappings": {
      "program_doc_type": {
        "properties": {
          "cast": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "name_analyzer"
              }
            }
          },
          "django_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "has_poster": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "imdb_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "kind": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "record_url_count": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "release_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "release_year": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "pattern"
          },
          "tms_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Analyzers:

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "keyword_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "name_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {"cast.name": "leonardo dicaprio"}
    }
}
```

First Page Result:

```
    {
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 62,
    "max_score": 12.046804,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "1077511",
        "_score": 12.046804,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt4007278",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "release_date": "2014-08-20",
          "title": "Carbon",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 2014,
          "django_id": 1077511,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "812919",
        "_score": 11.906615,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt2076929",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "Satori",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 2014,
          "django_id": 812919,
          "kind": "N/A",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "376792",
        "_score": 11.886408,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt0402538",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "Titanic: The Premiere",
          "has_poster": true,
          "release_year": 2000,
          "django_id": 376792,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "306106",
        "_score": 11.69776,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt0325727",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "release_date": "1998-08-16",
          "title": "Leo Mania",
          "has_poster": true,
          "release_year": 1998,
          "django_id": 306106,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "269743",
        "_score": 9.637444,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt0286234",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "Total Eclipse",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 1995,
          "django_id": 269743,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Agnieszka Holland"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "840945",
        "_score": 9.358208,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt2195237",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "release_date": "2004-12-01",
          "title": "MovieReal: The Aviator",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 2004,
          "django_id": 840945,
          "kind": "series",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Martin Scorsese"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "382168",
        "_score": 9.358208,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt0408269",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "release_date": "1998-09-29",
          "title": "To Leo with Love",
          "has_poster": true,
          "release_year": 1998,
          "django_id": 382168,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Jo Wyatt",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "846212",
        "_score": 7.2280827,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt2218442",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "Legacy of Secrecy",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 1947,
          "django_id": 846212,
          "kind": "N/A",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Robert De Niro",
            "D'Anthony Palms"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "595027",
        "_score": 7.1439695,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt1294988",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "release_date": "2006-09-27",
          "title": "Emporio Armani 'Red' One Night Only",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 2006,
          "django_id": 595027,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Kim Cattrall",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Beyoncé Knowles"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "752646",
        "_score": 7.1439695,
        "_source": {
          "imdb_id": "tt1826731",
          "tms_id": "",
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "release_date": "2009-06-02",
          "title": "Lives of Quiet Desperation: The Making of Revolutionary Road",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_year": 2009,
          "django_id": 752646,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Kathy Bates",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Kate Winslet"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I disabled field length norm and that seems to have improved it a lot but they still aren't all the same.  I'm still confused.  According to what i've read there are three ways to determine relevancy:

1. Term frequency
2. Inverse document frequency
3. Field length norm (disabled)

Since each program only has Leonardo Dicaprio one time it seems to me that they should have identical scores but they don't.  Maybe i'm misunderstanding.  Here are the updated settings after disabling field length norm:

Mapping:

```
{
  "programs": {
    "mappings": {
      "program_doc_type": {
        "properties": {
          "cast": {
            "type": "string",
            "norms": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "norms": {
                  "enabled": false
                },
                "analyzer": "name_analyzer"
              }
            }
          },
          "django_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "has_poster": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "imdb_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "kind": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "record_url_count": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "release_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "release_year": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "pattern"
          },
          "tms_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First Page Result:

```
{
  "took": 20,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 836,
    "max_score": 13.778852,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "421026",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "tms_id": "",
          "django_id": 421026,
          "imdb_id": "tt0449557",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_date": "2005-05-24",
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Jeffrey M. Schwartz",
            "Donald L. Barlett",
            "James B. Steele"
          ],
          "release_year": 2005,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "The Affliction of Howard Hughes: Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "555015",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "tms_id": "MV002510340000",
          "django_id": 555015,
          "imdb_id": "tt1130884",
          "has_poster": true,
          "release_date": "2010-02-19",
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Mark Ruffalo",
            "Ben Kingsley",
            "Max von Sydow"
          ],
          "release_year": 2010,
          "record_url_count": 2,
          "title": "Shutter Island"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "104669",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "tms_id": "",
          "django_id": 104669,
          "imdb_id": "tt0108330",
          "has_poster": true,
          "release_date": "1993-04-23",
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Robert De Niro",
            "Ellen Barkin",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Jonah Blechman"
          ],
          "release_year": 1993,
          "record_url_count": 1,
          "title": "This Boy's Life"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "846212",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "django_id": 846212,
          "title": "Legacy of Secrecy",
          "imdb_id": "tt2218442",
          "has_poster": false,
          "kind": "N/A",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Robert De Niro",
            "D'Anthony Palms"
          ],
          "release_year": 1947,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "tms_id": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "256632",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "django_id": 256632,
          "title": "The Movie Show",
          "imdb_id": "tt0271918",
          "has_poster": false,
          "kind": "series",
          "cast": [
            "Ray Brady",
            "Russell Crowe",
            "Larry Day",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ],
          "release_year": 1986,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "tms_id": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "269743",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "django_id": 269743,
          "title": "Total Eclipse",
          "imdb_id": "tt0286234",
          "has_poster": false,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Agnieszka Holland"
          ],
          "release_year": 1995,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "tms_id": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "1007190",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "tms_id": "",
          "django_id": 1007190,
          "imdb_id": "tt3391950",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_date": "2013-12-29",
          "kind": "series",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio",
            "Jonah Hill",
            "Martin Scorsese",
            "Terence Winter"
          ],
          "release_year": 2013,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "The Hollywood Reporter in Focus"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "1077511",
        "_score": 13.778852,
        "_source": {
          "tms_id": "",
          "django_id": 1077511,
          "imdb_id": "tt4007278",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_date": "2014-08-20",
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ],
          "release_year": 2014,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "Carbon"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "302615",
        "_score": 13.57246,
        "_source": {
          "django_id": 302615,
          "title": "Directors: James Cameron",
          "imdb_id": "tt0322031",
          "has_poster": true,
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Michael Biehn",
            "James Cameron",
            "Jamie Lee Curtis",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ],
          "release_year": 1997,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "tms_id": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "programs",
        "_type": "program_doc_type",
        "_id": "509785",
        "_score": 13.57246,
        "_source": {
          "tms_id": "",
          "django_id": 509785,
          "imdb_id": "tt0923573",
          "has_poster": false,
          "release_date": "2003-05-06",
          "kind": "movie",
          "cast": [
            "Frank Abagnale Jr.",
            "Amy Adams",
            "Nathalie Baye",
            "Leonardo DiCaprio"
          ],
          "release_year": 2003,
          "record_url_count": 0,
          "title": "'Catch Me If You Can': The Casting of the Film"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The results are MUCH improved but still the last 2 have different scores than the rest of the results.

Comment: this might not be relevant but you said 10 results and your outputs shows 70182 results? also your query is full query, there is nothing apart from match query, right?

Comment: I just retrieved all of the data fresh again and updated the post

Comment: Did you delete the index and reindex everything? It is giving me same score after disabling norms. If you didn't delete index completely then according to docs `Norms will not be removed instantly, but will be removed as old segments are merged into new segments as you continue indexing new documents. Any score computation on a field that has had norms removed might return inconsistent results since some documents won’t have norms anymore while other documents might still have norms.`

Comment: I deleted the entire index and reindexed but it's the same thing.

Comment: I see, I guess my dataset was very small, I could be wrong but this might be caused by scoring documents on different shards. You will be able to figure out score computation with [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-explain.html), Have a look at documents with different score and you will know why. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That does indeed look very useful.  I will investigate and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch relevancy default model is called TF/IDF. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/controlling-relevance.html).
The `_score` you see in your search hits is calculated by this model.

Basically, the score is a result of a calculation on three factors ([more info here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scoring-theory.html)):

1. Term frequency - How often does a term appear in a specific document? `TF`
2. Inverse document frequency - How often does the term appear in all documents in the collection? `IDF`
3. Field-length norm - How long is the field?

As you can infer from the above, because each document that contains `leonardo dicaprio` is different in its matching terms count, length of fields and matching terms count all over the index, its relevancy score is different.

Nevertheless, you get high scores for documents that contains `leonardo dicaprio` than those who doesn't.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've disabled field length norm now and the results are a lot better.  It still has a tiny bit of inconsistency that I can't rationalize.  I've updated my question with the details for that as well.

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistency?
Do you expect scores to be the same for all documents that contain the same search terms? If yes, well, it is not a good practice to depend on Elasticsearch scoring beside from getting the order of results sorted by relevancy for each specific query. Because the score factors are changing all the time, you may get different score values to the same consecutive query!

Comment: I was expecting different documents with identical fields to get the same score.  i.e. every document with the actor "Leonardo Dicaprio" would get the same score.  Why would that not be the case?